# What does a red dot on a minecraft map mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Title about says it all.

I built a map on minecraft.  It has a red dot on it.  My guess is that it means there's a bunch of lava at that spot.  could it mean anything else?

Comment: Anyone have a screenshot of this they can embed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really anything that is the majority of the blocks in the chunk shown, and is considered red by the maps. Here is a video to help explain it:

It isn't red wool because that is considered white since it shares the same data value as all the other wools. Lava, Netherbrick and TNT are detected as red. Bricks might turn out red also. If it isn't an area you have interacted with yet, I would have to say lava.

Answer (score -4):

It is lava because I was playing minecraft and I went to a red dot and there was a pool of lava. I think it only shows if the lava pool is above ground though. Because I know there is more lava in the world than just one pool.